# COCOS2D Particle Effect Collision

Tags: cocos2d-iphone, particles

I have no idea why it isn't working. The particle effect is located left bottom screen, instead of the part where it collided.

in .H file

```
    CCParticleExplosion *starsExplosion;
```

In .M file
Under the collision

```
        if(distance < 30) {
        starsCollected += 100;
        [_stars removeObject:stars];

        //Stars Explosion
        //starsExplosion.position = ccp(stars.contentSize.width, stars.contentSize.height);
        starsExplosion = [[CCParticleExplosion alloc] init];
        starsExplosion.position = ccp(stars.position.y, stars.position.x);
        starsExplosion.texture = [[CCTextureCache sharedTextureCache] addImage:@"star-icon.png"];

        [self addChild:starsExplosion];

        [self removeChild:stars cleanup:YES];
    }
```

I tried to use the `ContentSize.Width` and `height =`, no luck.
Tried to use `Position.x` and `y =`, also luck again.

Comment: Not that I'd think it's the source of your problem but aren't you swapping x and y when setting the position?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You switched your x and y coordinate. I  know, it's hard to see the errors in your own code, you probably just weren't thinking clearly at the time.

Change this:

```
starsExplosion.position = ccp(stars.position.y, stars.position.x);
```

To this:

```
starsExplosion.position = ccp(stars.position.x, stars.position.y);
```

Comment: Wow, that code actually works. Thank you so much. I didn't read it properly.